# Problems that can be shown by ”an epsilon of room”.

Tags: real-analysis, big-list

This might not be a question suitable here so apologies from posting it if so.

In Terence Tao’s blog he refers to something called ”An epsilon of room” and this seems to be a helpful way to prove for example inequalities in analysis. He goes on to say that

> If one has to show that $X \le Y$, try proving that $X \le Y+ \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon >0$.

I tried to find examples online from where I could gather a collection of problems that can be shown by his proposed method, but there isn’t much to find. Or perhaps most of the problems are ”masked” in a way that I don’t see this particular trick being used. If anyone knows some of these kind of problems I would appreciate if they could be posted here.

Comment: This is not really a "give me some homework problems" site. It is instead a question-and-answer site.

Comment: It seems to me that any epsilon-delta proof of a limit fits the description, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept here.

Comment: @LeeMosher Well, I think this person may just be asking for statements that may be proven using the trick.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes I see that the site is mostly for answering questions that can be answered pretty much in a ”binary” sense. By this I mean that there isn’t room for ”hand waving”. However as I see the sites main purpose is to educate and this is clearly an post that would be of help in that sense for many.

Comment: You could maybe add the big-list tag to this question.

Comment: This is just a special case of arguments done "by passing to limit". And it is not restricted to inequalities. For example, in linear algebra you often prove some property for diagonalizable matrices first, and then extend it to all matrices by passing to limit. Because every matrix is a limit of diagonalizable matrices. The property just has to behave continuously. That $\det(e^A)=e^{\text{tr}A}$ is proved this way. This is also used in measure theory a lot, something is first proved for step functions, etc.

Comment: You can do the inverse and show that 0.99999.....=1 because there's no way to find an "epsilon of room" between them

Answer (score 1):

Here are some statements that come to mind:

1. The [Lindelöf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_theorem) and its variants
2. The theorem that every probability measure defined on a Polish space is inner regular
3. The theorem that the continuous extension of a Lipschitz-continuous function that had previously only been defined on a dense subset is again Lipschitz-continuous with the same Lipschitz constant

Answer (score 1):

This happens frequently in the theory of elliptic and parabolic partial differential equations.

Here is a very classical example.

A $C^{2}$ function $u$ in an open set $\Omega$ is *harmonic* if its Laplacian vanishes everywhere, i.e. $-\Delta u(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$.

**Maximum principle:** If $u : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$ and twice continuously differentiable in $\Omega$, then $\max\left\{u(x) \, \mid \, x \in \Omega\right\} = \max\left\{u(y) \, \mid \, y \in \partial \Omega\right\}$.

Proof:  It's convenient to argue by contradiction.  Suppose, then, that the conclusion is false, i.e. $\max\{u(z) \, \mid \, z \in \partial \Omega\} < \max\{u(x) \, \mid \, x \in \Omega\}$.

I will take you up on that offer of $\epsilon$ of room.  Consider the function $v_{\epsilon}(x) = \max\{u(x) \, \mid \, x \in \Omega\} - \epsilon \|x\|^{2}$.  $u - v_{\epsilon}$ has a maximum $x_{\epsilon}$ somewhere in $\overline{\Omega}$.  For $\epsilon$ small enough, $x_{\epsilon} \in \Omega$ --- otherwise, $u$ would attain its maximum somewhere on the boundary.  (We have "room" to work with.)  Thus, since $x_{\epsilon}$ is an local maximum (in the interior), I can apply the the second derivative test to find
\begin{equation*}
-\Delta u(x_{\epsilon}) + \Delta v_{\epsilon}(x_{\epsilon}) = -\Delta (u - v_{\epsilon})(x_{\epsilon}) \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
so $-\Delta u(x_{\epsilon}) \geq -\Delta v_{\epsilon}(x_{\epsilon}) = 2 \epsilon d$.  This is impossible since $u$ is harmonic.

With experience, one realizes there is a geometric interpretation of this proof that is perfectly suited to the intuition that "we have room," but it would be cumbersome to explain here.